# Can Latin "inde" introduce a temporal clause?

Tags: grammar-choice, meaning, aeneis, vergilius, subordinate-clause

Lines one and two of book 2 of Vergil's Aeneid sparked this question:

> Conticuere omnes intentique ora tenebant
>   inde toro pater Aeneas sic orsus ab alto:

I had two interpretations. My first interpretation is that the *-que* in *intentique* links the verbs *conticuere* (perfect active indicative) and *tenebant*. However, that makes it unclear as to how the second line connects grammatically to the first unless *inde* can somehow be used as an introduction to a temporal clause, but I was under the impression (perhaps too narrow) that only *dum, cum, donec, postquam, ubi*, and *ut* could introduce temporal clauses.

My other interpretation was that *-que* links the two clauses with the first line just having a missing conjunction for poetic effect: "All were silent [and] attentive were holding their mouths and from there ...". However, this version feels weird considering the placement of *-que*.

What would a contemporary Roman perceive the *-que* as connecting?

Comment: It occurs to me now that another possibility would be to repunctuate the line (since Vergil's original had no punctuation) and put a period after *tenebant*. That way *inde* starts the next sentence and becomes a simple adverb.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regarding the question in the title, [Lewis and Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dinde) (seemingly this community's [favorite dictionary](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/867/which-online-latin-dictionaries-should-i-use-and-why)) lists among the meanings of *inde* the following: *from that time*, *thenceforward*, *since*, *after that*, *thereafter*, *thereupon*, *then*. Just in case, there is the same entry on [other dictionary](http://latin.campus.nd.edu/cgi-bin/lookup.pl?stem=inde&ending=). The same idea applies to *unde*.

Relative pronouns/adverbs that mark location (even with movement) can in fact mark time as well.

Regarding the role of *-que*, remember that it always works as a suffix to the second term in the conjunction. A valid rephrasing (at least for the sake of understanding) could be:

> *Conticuere omnes* et *intenti ora tenebant*

A plausible word-to-word translation would be:

> They all fell silent and kept their mouths stretched

Looking at a couple of translations, *intenti ora tenere* is read as *pay deep attention*, *keep rapt gaze*. All of them read *inde* as *then* or a synonym of it.

Hope it helps.

Comment: 'Kept their mouths stretched'? Is that an idiom? I think it is "omnes conticuere" et "intenti, tenebant ora" (They all fell silent, and, rapt, they held their tongues / Thereupon, ...).

Answer (score 3):

What your question really seems to be about is whether *inde* can serve as a *subordinate conjunction*, like *dum, cum,* etc., introducing a subordinate clause, to be translated as "when" or "while". You ask this, because you feel that a conjunction is needed to link the two lines.

If you look at the link to Lewis & Short above, you will see that *inde* (unlike *unde*) is exclusively used as an adverb, not as a conjunction. And I have never seen it used as a conjunction. It therefore seems impossible to treat it as a conjunction.

You were correct about *-que*: it links *conticuere omnes* with *intenti ora tenebant*, so it cannot serve to connect this line with the next either.

The "solution" is that the Romans normally used neither commas nor full stops, and the punctuation is not Virgil's. The punctuation chosen in your edition seems to be based on on modern rules; but you can just add a comma between the lines, or even a full stop, to make it work. Or you could read it as an *[asyndeton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asyndeton)*, where a conjunction is omitted to rhetorical effect, à la *veni, vidi, vici*: imagine something like *cum* or *et* was omitted. All of this is legitimate in editions of classical Latin texts.